Go: redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS goes to localhost
I'm trying to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Go, but no matter what it goes to localhost:
I define the servers and run them:
httpServer = &http.Server{
        Addr:    login.HttpPORT,
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(redirectNonSecure),
    }

    httpsServer = &http.Server{
        Addr:      login.HttpsPORT,
        TLSConfig: &tlsConf,
    }

    errChan := make(chan error, 2)

    go func() {
        log.Println("Starting HTTP server on :8081")
        if err := httpServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        log.Println("Starting HTTPS server on :8082")
        if err := httpsServer.ListenAndServeTLS(certPath, keyPath); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }()

    log.Fatalf("Server error: %v", <-errChan)

And here is the redirect func:
func redirectNonSecure(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    redirectURL := "https://" + r.Host + httpsServer.Addr + r.RequestURI
    http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURL, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
}

It always redirects to https://127.0.0.1:8082 and it should return https://ipAddr:8082
If i run it from localhost there's no issue, obviously, if i go directly to the https without redirect it also worls fine, this is just when redirecting.
I also tried hardcoding the IP inside the redirect function but it still redirects to localhost which makes me think there's something else at play here.
EDIT: I'll share here my whole main function in case there's something outside of the provided code that's causing some conflict, i'm really lost here:
func main() {
    logger.CreateLogger()
    var login Login
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &login)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    dbConn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s", login.DBUser, login.DBPass, login.DBHost, login.Dbase)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbConn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Couldn't connect!")
        logger.Error.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    database = db

    makePaths()
    certificates, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certPath, keyPath)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    tlsConf := tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{certificates},
    }
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/api/pages", APIPage).
        Methods("GET").
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/pages/{page_guid:[0-9a-zA-Z\\-]+}", APIPage).
        Methods("GET").
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/page/{page_guid:[0-9a-zA-Z\\-]+}/comments", APICommentPost).
        Methods("POST").
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/page/{page_guid:[0-9a-zA-Z\\-]+}/comments/{comment_id:[0-9]+}", APICommentPut).
        Methods("PUT").
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/page/{page_guid:[0-9a-zA-Z\\-]+}", ServePage).
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/register", RegisterPOST).
        Methods("POST").
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/login", LoginPOST).
        Methods("POST").
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/logout", LogoutPOST).
        Methods("POST").
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/", RedirIndex).
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/home", ServeIndex).
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/cookietest", startHandler).
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/middle", createCookieHandler).
        Schemes("https")
    r.HandleFunc("/cookietestdelete", deleteCookieHandler).
        Schemes("https")
    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))

    httpServer = &http.Server{
        Addr:    login.HttpPORT,
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(redirectNonSecure),
    }

    httpsServer = &http.Server{
        Addr:      login.HttpsPORT,
        TLSConfig: &tlsConf,
    }

    errChan := make(chan error, 2)

    go func() {
        log.Println("Starting HTTP server on :8081")
        if err := httpServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        log.Println("Starting HTTPS server on :8082")
        if err := httpsServer.ListenAndServeTLS(certPath, keyPath); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }()

    log.Fatalf("Server error: %v", <-errChan)

}

could there be some path precedence that's making it behave this way?

httpsServer.Addr has the value taken from login.HttpsPORT which, judging purely from its name, does not appear to contain a host. Anyway, based on the presented examples, one never knows.

Also, if I were to write such code, I'd probably take the URL to operate on from the incoming http.Request, copied it, patched the protocol part (possibly reset the port part) and serialized to the string. I mean, if you only want to change the protocol, it's sensble to use the URL which is confirmed to have worked to reach your server.

«httpsServer.Addr has the value taken from login.HttpsPORT which…» — maybe it's not quite clear what I meant so let me expand on this. To me, it appears like you consider this Addr field to be somewhat magic in the sense that once the server starts it contains some "actual" address it listens on. This is not the case; this field is merely used by Listen* methods; and listening on a socket might actually listen on an unbounded number of addresses — any one, which is able to be used to reach your server. This also explains why http.Server does not have anything like MyRealAddress().

@kostix i get it, but as i stated i actually tried hardcoding the redirect address like redirectURL := "https://IPAddrs"+ httpsServer.Addr + r.RequestURI instead of redirectURL := "https://" + r.Host + httpsServer.Addr + r.RequestURI and it still redirects to localhost, that's why i don't understand what is happening. Btw, httpsServer.Addr only has the port, that's why i take the ip from the request r.Host

Can you add the code where you hardcoded the IP address to the question please? That is kind of the key to your problem here, where you take the actual data from is a complete red herring if not even hardcoding it works. Also you should log out the actual url that is composed to see what it contains. And you could do an even more simplified test; hardcode a url but make it https://stackoverflow.com, no string concatenation at all. If not even that redirect works then there is definitely something very funky going on.

(1) The question states that the expected redirect URL is https://ipAddr:8082.  What is ipAddr?  There is no other mention of it in the question.   (2) What is the URL that you typed into the browser address bar? (3) Is a proxy involved?

@Gimby you can check how and where i harcoded the IP in the comment above, i tried logging the info but somehow it's not spitting out logs, which makes me think it's not entering in redirectNonSecure i provided my whole main in case it helps, i'm very confused but am thinking there's some kind of precedence in the way i set up the paths that's screwing it up.

@CeriseLimón 1- ipAddr is the actual IP that localhost is on where other machines can connect to it, it works fine if accessed directly, but on redirect it's sent to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) 2- the url typed is ipAddr:Port which redirects to localhost as opposed to https://ipAddr:anotherPort which opens the page correctly 3 - i don't believe there's a proxy involved, the server is in a VM i setup and i'm trying to access it from outside, again the problem is only on redirect

(1) Unless there's a proxy involved, the value of r.Host is ipAddr:Port for a request to http://ipAddr:Port.   Add a print statement to the redirectNonSecure to confirm. (2) The URL "https://" + r.Host + httpsServer.Addr + r.RequestURI can include two :port strings.  Split r.Host to get a host with no port.

Use the request host with the port in login.httpsPORT:
func redirectNonSecure(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Get host without port.
    host, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(r.Host)
    if err != nil {
        // Use request host as is if request host does not
        // include a port number or there is another error.
        host = r.Host
    }

    // Add port to host if needed.
    _, port, _ := net.SplitHostPort(login.httpsPORT)
    if port != "433" {
        host = net.JoinHostPort(host, port) 
    }

    redirectURL := "https://" + host + r.RequestURI
    http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURL, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
}


Unfortunately the issue still remains, it redirects to localhost, that's why i indicated that it's still redirecting to localhost even though i tried hardcoding the IP into the redirect function, like so "https://IPAddrs"+ httpsServer.Addr + r.RequestURI, i don't understand what is happening or if there is some path precedence in main that's making it behave this way? It's really weird.
